# Chrome Ajax Basic Auth - same credential submitted again

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, authentication

With our webapp,

user supplies username/password to use with basic auth to connect to 3rd party webservice using AJAX

if that 3rd party webservice returns 401 because username/password is incorrect, 
an Authentication dialog pops up.

All good.

User then enters the correct credential and click OK.

But Chrome does not use this correct credential, but instead re-submit the old incorrect credential entered previously.

Has anyone seen this 'bug' ?
[image: chrome basic auth issue]

```
getLayersFromCapabilities: function() {

    var baseOgcUrl = $('input#ogc-url').val();

    var capabilitiesUrl = this.api.Utilities.appendQueryStringQuestionMarkIfNeeded(baseOgcUrl);

    Spinner && Spinner.show();

    var getCapabilitiesAjaxOptions = {
        url: capabilitiesUrl,            
        dataType: 'xml',
        context: this,
        success: function(xmlDoc) {
            Spinner.hide();
            var capabilities = capabilitiesFormat.read(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc));

            if( capabilities && capabilities.featureTypeList && capabilities.featureTypeList.featureTypes ) {
                //----------------
                // WFS
                //----------------

                this.displayLayerProperties();
            }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Spinner.hide();
            console.log("Error retrieving GetCapabilities XML, make sure you are authenticated.");
            return;
        }
    };

    this.addBasicAuthHeadersIfNeeded(getCapabilitiesAjaxOptions);

    $.ajax(getCapabilitiesAjaxOptions);
},


addBasicAuthHeadersIfNeeded: function(wfsAjaxOptions) {

    wfsAjaxOptions.headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(this.getOgcUsername() + ":" + this.getOgcPassword())
    };
    wfsAjaxOptions.xhrFields = {
        withCredentials: true
    };

},
```

Request/Response Headers

```
    #1. AJAX Preflight  
OPTIONS https://thirdparty.com/WebApp/Web/SAAS/Api/WFS/v1/WfsServer?&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities&service=wfs HTTP/1.1
Host: thirdparty.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://myserver.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://myserver.com/app1/?project=Sample&touch=false&debug=debug
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

#2. AJAX Preflight Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myserver.com
Allow: GET,DELETE,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 07:37:46 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-T1-Compressed-By-CompressFilter: gzip
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive


#3. AJAX auth request
GET https://thirdparty.com/WebApp/Web/SAAS/Api/WFS/v1/WfsServer?&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities&service=wfs HTTP/1.1
Host: thirdparty.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://myserver.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://myserver.com/app1/?project=Sample&touch=false&debug=debug
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: MaxScreenMode=false; Theme/T2/SAAS=NewYork; RequestingArea=WebServices


#4. AJAX auth response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myserver.com
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 07:37:47 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: RequestingArea=WebServices; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 07:37:47 GMT; path=/WebApp/Web/; secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive


#5. 2nd AJAX Auth request, user enters different credential in Browser Auth Dialog, but Chrome puts the old Basic Authorization Credential, again
GET https://thirdparty.com/WebApp/Web/SAAS/Api/WFS/v1/WfsServer?&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities&service=wfs HTTP/1.1
Host: thirdparty.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://myserver.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://myserver.com/app1/?project=Sample&touch=false&debug=debug
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: MaxScreenMode=false; Theme/T2/SAAS=NewYork; RequestingArea=WebServices


#6. 2nd AJAX auth response, unauthorized, because it was using the incorrect credential entered in step #3 above
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myserver.com
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 07:37:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: RequestingArea=WebServices; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 07:38:00 GMT; path=/WebApp/Web/; secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Does the request/response headers look alright ?

the code is just jQuery.ajax

Comment: Also shouldn't Chrome re-authenticate using username/password that the user enters in the dialog, instead of re-using the old one?
We can't control that from Javascript, can we ?

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff , added the relevant code for client side auth

Comment: No, this.getOgcUsername()/this.getOgcPassword() return old values, however that bit of code is not called again, when user tries to Log In using Chrome Authentication Required dialog box (Step #2 in screenshot)

Comment: No, user enters the 'new' username/password in Chrome Authentication Dialog (#2 in screenshot above). But Chrome doesn't use that.
Refer to http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/

Comment: Ok, i have no idea what's going on. I remove useless comments  and hope someone with more experiment to this would be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!